# O que causa o erro "Unknown renderer type" no Google charts?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp, google-charts

Ola, estou fazendo um programa para gerar gráficos e começou a aparecer esse erro em alguns, mas o estranho é que, os gráficos são gerados a partir de alguns checkbox selecionados, então, quando você seleciona certa quantia de checkbox da certo, outra quantia da errado, alguém saberia me dizer o que causa isso para tentar concertar esse erro?

Gerar os graficos:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < @Model.pdisAno.Count; j++)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
            var teste = "teste" + @j
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(teste)

            function teste() {

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Ano');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Quantidade de Operadores');

                @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.AnosPdi[j].Count; i++)
            {
                @: data.addRow(['@Model.AnosPdi[j][i]',@Model.conAnos[j][i]]);
                                                            }

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: '@Model.pdisAno[j]',
                        subtitle: 'Quantidade de Operarios por ano'
                    },
                    chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '50%' }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material' + '@j'));

                chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Esta parte para gerar as divs e mostrar os graficos:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < @Model.pdisAno.Count; i = i + 3)
{
    string nome1 = "columnchart_material" + i;
    string nome2 = "columnchart_material" + (i + 1);
    string nome3 = "columnchart_material" + (i + 2);
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%">
                <div id="@nome1" style="height:250px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%">
                <div id="@nome2" style="height:250px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%">
                <div id="@nome3" style="height:250px;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código?

Comment: coloquei, aparentemente o que ta causando o erro é essa parte do código, preciso gerar esses grafícos de forma dinâmica, tentei fazer assim mas ta dando esse erro

Comment: Mostra a linha que esta dando o erro no console?

Comment: Não, o erro é mostrado onde deveria mostrar o grafico

Comment: Consegui resolver, valeu pela ajuda ^^

Answer (score 1):

A linha "google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });" deve estar fora do loop.

O método google.charts.load só pode ser chamado uma vez na página.